# Annotate based on a set of keywords

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with strings in every row like this:

```
col_name
col_string
It is a rainy day
Daily exercise
My name is
Hello
```

I would like to annotate my dataset using this rules

```
  day <- c("day", "daily")
    name <- c("name")
```

And have as a final output this (a second column based on the previous groups):

```
col_string, col_annotated
It is a rainy day, day
Daily exercise, day
My name is, name
Hello, NA
```

Is it possible to make it?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(col_annotated = case_when(grepl("day", .$col_string, T)  ~ "day",
                                   grepl("name", .$col_string, T) ~ "name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- data.frame(col_string = c('It is a rainy day',
                               'Daily exercise',
                               'My name is',
                               'Hello'))


d$col_annotated <- ifelse(grepl('day', d$col_string, T)  | grepl('daily', d$col_string, T), 'day', 
                          ifelse(grepl('name', d$col_string, T), 'name', NA))

d
##          col_string col_annotated
## 1 It is a rainy day           day
## 2    Daily exercise           day
## 3        My name is          name
## 4             Hello          <NA>
```